# ASP.NET IIS error while deploying Excel libraries

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, web-config

I am getting error while deployed the asp.net Application in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008. I have referenced Excel 2007 which is also present in Windows Server 2008.

Here is my web.config code

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualC, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Getting following error message

```
Server Error in '/dev' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\web.config    Line: 32

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: show code your web.config file?

Comment: Added the web.config file code for reference

Comment: are you sure, you have required excel 2007 dll's in the bin?

Comment: Server side Office automation is doomed.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution.

```
1.Open Visual studio  -> visual Studio tools -> Visual studio command prompt

2.Run following command 
C:\Windows\system32>gacutil /i c:\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v9.0 (Location of dll)

3. Restart your computer and try.
```

Comment: The server dont have Visual Studio, its a production server